# selecting multiple records where count is some value

Tags: mysql, count, record, where-clause

There is a huge database with more than 500k values, but with only one table having all the data. I need to extract some of it for a given condition.

Table structure is like this,

```
column_a | column_b    
A        | 30    
A        | 40    
A        | 70    
B        | 25    
B        | 45    
C        | 10    
C        | 15    
C        | 25
```

I need to extract all the data having a count(column_a) = 3. the catch is that i need to get all the three records too. Like this,

```
column_a | column_b 
A        | 30    
A        | 40    
A        | 70    
C        | 10    
C        | 15    
C        | 25
```

I have tried to do this with a query like this

```
select column_a,column_b group by column_a having count(*)=3;
```

Here i get the correct values for column_a but only one record from each.

Thanks in advance,
Bhashithe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to `INNER JOIN` your original table to a subquery which identifies the `column_a` records which come in groups of exactly 3.

```
SELECT t1.column_a, t1.column_b
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT column_a, COUNT(*)
    FROM table
    GROUP BY column_a
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
) t2
ON t1.column_a = t2.column_a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested query, if you want.
Here, inner query fetches the records having `column_a` size equals to 3 and outer query displays all the records using the `'IN'` clause.

```
SELECT t.column_a, t.column_b FROM table t
WHERE t.column_a IN 
(
    SELECT t1.column_a FROM table t1
    GROUP BY t1.column_a
    HAVING COUNT(t1.column_a) = 3
) 
ORDER BY t.column_a;
```